# how do I rotate a qlabel in py qt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qlabel

I'm trying to rotate a QLabel widget and can't find a proper way to do so.
I managed to do so only if it contains an image, but not if it contains only text.
Any ideas or suggestions?